# How could I know whichever a file is newly edited and changed in linux? Where should I refer to?

Tags: linux, shell

Someone has using my account to edit something, and I would like to know which file is changed by him. I have tried scaning "history" but it was really a hard work because history list all the files opened,not exactly the files changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you know roughly when the files were modified, you can use `find` with the `-mmin` or `-mtime` options.

From the `find` man page, this is what the options mean:

> **-mmin n**
>          File's data was last modified n minutes ago.
>
> **-mtime n**
>          File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.

For example, to find files modified in your home directory in the last hour, but not within the last 10 mins you can use:

```
find /home/username -type f -mmin -60 -mmin +10
```

Comment: OK,it worked pretty well.thank you very much.How I wish to vote up your answer but I was limited cause I only have 0 reputation...

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer if it worked for you.